# Sqlite3 database file can be deleted and is still accessible

Tags: c++, c, sqlite

I am using SQLite3 in my RTOS system. I've set the configuration such that it will lock for each transaction. On my system I end up with one file on the drive

"SQLDB.db"

When there is a transaction you can usually see a lock file if you are fast enough. "SQLDB.db.lock".

What's driving me wild is that when I delete "SQLDB.db" I still have the ability to do SELECTs from the database, but I cannot insert. It's not a caching issue because I can do selects on multiple tables (that I haven't done any operations on before rebooting the system).

So my question is, is the DB file being cached? Is it saved in RAM somewhere? How is it possible to query this ghost database?

Comment: What is the c and c++ context here?

Comment: Are you closing it ? after you end up with all your tasks ?

Comment: @Rochi I was only closing it when shutting down the system. Does it need to be closed after each transaction? And opened for each?

Comment: I think that if you do not close it you cannot delete it and you will access to it until the end . Try to Close() it and delete .. and let me know .

Answer (score 0):

In Unix, when you delete a file, the directory entry is deleted immediately, but the actual file data is deleted only when all open file handles have been closed.

Apparently, your RTOS behaves the same.